# Android multiple checkboxes on a single table row

Tags: android, checkbox, android-tablelayout

Not sure what I am doing wrong, but I am trying to put 5 check boxes in a single table row. The row seems to end after the first check box, and the remaining 4 check boxes are appearing outside the row. Here is the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal" >
        <TextView  
            android:id="@+id/txtView1"  
            android:layout_width="match_parent"  
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
            android:textStyle="bold"  
            android:typeface="serif"  
            android:textSize="18sp"  
            android:text="@string/start_head"  
            android:gravity="center"  
            android:layout_span="5"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp" >

        </TextView>  
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp" >

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/chkAtm"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/atm" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/chkGift"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/giftcard" />
       <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/chkRing"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/ring" />
       <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/chkMerchant"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/merchant" />
       <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/chkCod"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/cod" /> 

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal" >
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnRun"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:text="@string/run"
            android:layout_span="5" />

    </TableRow>


</TableLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your second CheckBox hasn't got android:layout_height, check it ;)

Comment: Reason # 100 to not code when you have a hangover! Thanks, that fixed it.